# Getting different sessions from httpServletrequest and DWR httpServletrequest

Tags: java, servlets, dwr

I am working on a legacy application,

where when the user logs in the request goes to filter and will be redirected to the home page after validation. After that whenever user clicks on any link it will be verified whether user is an admin user using DWR.

The problem is we are getting different sessions when we fetch the session from

```
httpServletrequest.getSession(true);
```

and

```
WebContextFactory.get().getHttpServletRequest().getSession();
```

because of this when ever we try to get the user details from session we are getting null in the session what we are getting from DWR.

How to get same session which is created in httpServletrequest using DWR also.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/javaapi.html):

> WebContext is used when you are in a DWR thread. It uses a ThreadLocal variable to connect you to the running container.

Are You in a DWR thread when You invoke `WebContextFactory.get()`?

Alternatively You can include servlet objects in parameters list of Your remoted method object.

> DWR will not include it on the generated stub and upon a call of the method it will fill it in automagically.

I did it like this and it worked. I get the same session as in a standard request.

```
public class Remote {
    public void method(int param, HttpSession httpSession) { ... }
}
```